# Box Cox transformation in R, apply to a column

Tags: r, statistics

I have skewed data that I need to normalize in order to make a t-test and I struggle to find an implementation of the [Box-Cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation) taking a specified lambda. I tried to use a log but for a few data points, it does not work quite well.

I come from Python where there is this function:

```
from scipy.special import boxcox
>>> boxcox([1, 4, 10], 2.5)
array([0.,12.4,  126.09110641])
```

where `2.5` would be the lambda specified. This function can then be applied to a whole column.

I would like to find its implementation in R but so far I have only found the `boxcox` function that gives me the best lambda parameter in the `MASS` package but I cannot seem to find a way to apply any lambda I want.

Comment: A t-test does not require normal data. Search cross validated for more information.

Comment: Package `forecast`, function `BoxCox`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `boxcox` function from the `EnvStat` pacakge (see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/EnvStats/versions/2.3.1/topics/boxcox)).
There you can specify `lambda`:

```
library(EnvStat)
boxcox(1:10, lambda = 2.5, optimize = F)
```